# Delete docker image with child dependencies, but with <none> tag

Tags: docker, containers

I have these two images. I can't remove the second one, I can't assign it a TAG.

The first image was create by committing a stopped container of the second image.

```
ubuntu                        v1         f15ee69edd3f   About a minute ago   147MB

ubuntu                        <none>     27941809078c   10 days ago          77.8MB
```

Does anyone know what to do?

Worst case, on a separate computer I have a docker image without both name and tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use `docker system prune` and for other options like filters see documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

And if you want to remove image with specific hash

```
docker rmi -f fd484f19954f
```

Comment: I got this message: Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 9df2968b00d3 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images

Comment: @Alessandro refer this [link](https://www.devopsroles.com/how-to-delete-docker-image-with-dependent-child-images/)

Comment: `docker rmi $(docker images -q) -f` deletes **all** the images...